# Workflow to Copy Item to a Library with External Data field?

Tags: external-content-type, external-data-column

I have a workflow that is triggered when a item is approved, it looks at the status and copies it over to a archive library with a external data field.

Problem I am having is when the copy happens everything copies over except the field for the external data field. My example is I have a field named "User ID" that is a single line text field and I want that data in that field to copy over to the other library that has a external data field called "User ID" that will in return will populate the other fields.

I have tried using the "Update Item" with no success.

Comment: Forget the copy. It wont even let me set that field with a workflow inside the library. I tried it as a string and every other type. Is there not a way to set a external data field with a string?

Answer (score 0):

Setting an external data column via a workflow doesn't work. The wf runs with no error, but no value is stored inside the external column.

This matter has been discussed [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/how-to-automate-entry-of-external-column-data-in-bcs) before.