# set BCS field using powershell

Tags: powershell, external-data

I have an external data field. I have to copy the value from list to another list.
How i can set the value in the other list?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://intranet/CAC/RestrictedAreaManco/
$listProspect = $web.Lists["Prospects"]


$Fund = Get-SPWeb http://manco-intranet/sites/clients
$listFunds = $Fund.Lists["New Fund"]

foreach($item in $listProspect.Items | Where {$_["Approved"] -eq "string;#Approved"}) 
#Approved is a calculated Column so it's input have the value string;#..
{
  $newItem["Investment Compliance Provider"] = $item["Investment Compliance"]
     $item["Investment Compliance"]

  $newItem.Update()

}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the value is displayed in the display form but not filled in the Edit form!! how i can fill it in the edit form please?

Comment: Are you using custom new, edit and display form? By what method, you're binding/getting the data to/from list respectively?

Comment: No it's not a custom form. I tried the method mentioned above but it work only in the display Form

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's some issue with powershell.
You could refer below SSOM code to copy external data.

The following code to iterate through all the items in my `Resumes` document library, read the value from the "regular" `EmployeeID` field for each item, set the "external" `EmplData_ID` value, then set all the "secondary field" values based on this value.

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList resumesList = web.Lists["Resumes"];

        foreach (SPListItem item in resumesList.Items)
        {
            SPBusinessDataField dataField = item.Fields["EmplData_ID"] as SPBusinessDataField;
            // Set the "external" Employee ID field value
            item[dataField.RelatedField] = item["EmployeeID"];
            // Now set all the secondary field values
            SetSecondaryFields(item, dataField, GetEntityInstance("http://sp2010srv", "Employee", int.Parse(item["EmployeeID"].ToString())));
            item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the two helper methods `GetEntityInstance` and `SetSecondaryFields`:

```
    private static IEntityInstance GetEntityInstance(string nameSpace, string entityName, int entityId)
{
    BdcService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>();
    IMetadataCatalog catalog = service.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.Current);
    IEntity entity = catalog.GetEntity(nameSpace, entityName);
    ILobSystemInstance LobSysteminstance = entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;
    IEntityInstance entInstance = null;

    // Get methods collection 
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IMethod> method in entity.GetMethods())
    {
        // Get current method's instance 
        IMethodInstance methodInstance = method.Value.GetMethodInstances()[method.Key];
        // Execute specific finder method. 
        if (methodInstance.MethodInstanceType == MethodInstanceType.SpecificFinder)
        {
            // Create new identity 
            Identity id = new Identity(entityId);
            // Execute specific finder method and get the entity instance 
            entInstance = entity.FindSpecific(id, entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value);
        }
    } 

    return entInstance;
}

private static void SetSecondaryFields(SPListItem listItem, SPBusinessDataField dataField, IEntityInstance entityInstance)
{
    // Convert the entity to a formatted datatable
    DataTable dtBDCData = entityInstance.EntityAsFormattedDataTable;

    // Set the BCS field itself (Display Value)
    listItem[dataField.Id] = dtBDCData.Rows[0][dataField.BdcFieldName].ToString();

    // Get the specific finder method to get the columns that returns
    IMethodInstance method = entityInstance.Entity.GetMethodInstances(MethodInstanceType.SpecificFinder)[0].Value;
    ITypeDescriptorCollection oDescriptors = method.GetReturnTypeDescriptor().GetChildTypeDescriptors()[0].GetChildTypeDescriptors();

    // Set the column names to the correct values
    foreach (ITypeDescriptor oType in oDescriptors)
    {
        if (oType.ContainsLocalizedDisplayName())
        {
            if (dtBDCData.Columns.Contains(oType.Name))
            {
                dtBDCData.Columns[oType.Name].ColumnName = oType.GetLocalizedDisplayName();
            }
        }
    }

    // get the secondary field display names; these should be set
    string[] sSecondaryFieldsDisplayNames = dataField.GetSecondaryFieldsNames();

    // loop through the fields and set each column to its value
    foreach (string columnNameint in sSecondaryFieldsDisplayNames)
    {
        Guid gFieldID = listItem.Fields[String.Format("{0}: {1}", dataField.Title, columnNameint)].Id;
        listItem[gFieldID] = dtBDCData.Rows[0][columnNameint].ToString();
    }
}
```

Refer: [Automate connectivity of external data in BCS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/how-to-automate-entry-of-external-column-data-in-bcs?rq=1)