# Update all BCS Field in SPSite using Powershell

Tags: powershell, bcs

When i delete an item in my external list, it's not deleted automatically from the list where i use the BCS Field. I have to click Refresh. I'm using this BCS in many lists.

I'm looking for a scheduled script powershell, which allow me updating all the BCS fields in my SPSite.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here are some examples:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/964fba7a-fc64-412a-829e-42766c34db20/sponline-updating-bcs-columnssecondary-columns-via-powershell?forum=sharepointadmin
- [How to automate entry of external column data in BCS?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/how-to-automate-entry-of-external-column-data-in-bcs)
- https://blog.portiva.nl/2014/09/04/setting-an-bdc-external-list-field-with-powershell-and-retrieving-the-bcdid/

*Hope it helps!*